Settings not opening Ubuntu 24.04
I recently downgraded to Linux 6.8 because 6.10 wasn't supported by nvidia-driver-550. I also disabled amdgpu so that my laptop would be running solely on my nvidia graphics card. Now when I click on the setting icon, it shows the orange dot, but then it disappears.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling gnome-control-center and rebooting, but I had no luck.
I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu and Linux troubleshooting techniques and I haven't found anything on google yet. Please help.

No current version of Ubuntu uses kernel 6.10 series. Why did you install the 6.10 series kernel in the first place?

Does this answer help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1526460/29270
